# Spork not working Ubuntu (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrat, spork, ubuntu-11.04

I have a porblem with spork, i'm currently starting to use ubuntu to develop on rails and i every time i try to run spork [-b] it gives me an error, i hope u can help me i have webrat 7.1 and spork 0.9.0.rc5

undefined method `basename' for "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/webrat-0.7.1":String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a bug.
In spork 0.9.0rc7 it is resolved.
So you should update spork.

$ bundle update spork